# Can the python logging function return the log message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, python-logging

I want to log my error messages as well as raise an exception with the same message.
For eg:

```
try:
   foo()
except Exception as error:
    error_message = "Custom error message"
    logger.error(error_message)
    raise RunttimeError(error_message)
```

I want to do something like this

```
try:
   foo()
except Exception as error:
    raise RunttimeError(logger.error("Custom error message"))
```

I want the logger.error() to return the error message.(This is not only for logger.error(), but for all other logger functions)

Is it possible?

I tried creating a Custom Handler for python logger which returns the msg provided to it, but that did not work. It behaves similar to Python StreamHandler

Comment: No, it does not return the error message, and your three-line solution is entirely appropriate. Not everything needs to be condensed to one line. You could make your own function which logs *and returns* the message if you insist…

Comment: The argument is not the complete message, "only" the format string that may have optional arguments. Python tries to postpone the formatting until it is clear the message will be logged. Some messages are not logged because of levels and filters.